# How Can I run .net core self-contained deploy project without cmd (cmd should not prompt after running the project)

Tags: c#, cmd, .net-core, azure-devops

I have .net code SDC project, while running that project it open command prompt host my output on localhost://8000, now if I close the cmd my application will also stop.

I don't want to stop my application, Can I run my application without launching the cmd.

My .Net-core version is 2.1, 
I am publishing my code through command

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win10-x64
```

now it will publish my code under publish folder from there I am running my .exe

```
abc.exe arg1 arg2
```

it will execute the .exe and cmd will be open

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\User\..
Now listening on: http://[::]:8000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My requirement is it should not open I don't want to cmd open to run this application, just after running the .exe it should come out from cmd and application should keep on running.

Comment: `start /b dotnet yourdll.dll`

Comment: from where you want me to run this , same place from where I am currently running my .exe, if so then it is giving me error  
"No executable found matching command "dotnet-mssql.dll"

Comment: @DiptiKumari There's no `cmd` or prompt involved here at all. If you start your application from the *console*, the default log output will also go to the console. If you start it by double clicking, the application will still start. If you start it as a service or unattended, it will still work.

Comment: @DiptiKumari Why did you add the `azure-devops` tag? Do you want to host your web app on Azure, IIS or NGINX? In that case the question shouldn't be about the console, it should be how to host an ASP.NET Core application on Azure or another web server

Comment: Yes, i am trying to create Azure release pipeline for same application and there after adding Execute cmd task I am getting this problem.
the Task keeps on running and release is never going to end

Comment: you may also try `start /b abc.exe arg1 arg2`

Comment: @vasily.sib that's no different that `abc.exe arg1 arg2`. It has nothing to do with how the application itself runs either

Comment: @DiptiKumari you're trying to start a *web application* in a Release Pipeline, that listens to port 8080. Web apps don't terminate unless the administrator (you) terminates them or they exit themselves in response to some event. Did you create the wrong type of project perhaps? If you want to create a tool, use the `console` template

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is true, that there is no difference between running `dotnet yourdll.dll` and `abc.exe`, but as I see from OP's comment he is trying to run not its own dll (like `abc.dll`), but `dotnet-mssql.dll`, so I think that it is easier to tell him to run his `abc.exe`. The actual advise in my comments is to use `start /b` which will run his app in the background.